# Pandas : join 2 tables and compare the fields having the same name except for suffix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have joined 2 tables having same fields on a key and using a suffix int and prod for each.

`int

```
id  measure1 measure2
123 45       23
134 09       12
```

prod

```
id  measure1 measure2
123 16       45
134 65       01`
```

```
df=prod.merge(int,on='id',suffixes=['_prod','_int'])
```

joined table would look like this.

`

```
id  measure1_int measure2_int  measure1_prod measure2_prod
123 45           23            16            45 
134 09           12            65            01`
```

I want to create a measure , column deviation_{measure_name} like so

`

```
id  measure1_int measure2_int  measure1_prod measure2_prod  deviation_measure1 deviation_measure2
123 45           23            16            45             29                 -22
134 09           12            65            01             -56                11`
```

this is what I have done, what would be the fastest way to acheive this?

```
def f(a,b):
    return a-b
    
for i in li:
    df[str('deviation_'+i)]=df.apply(lambda x: f(x[str(i+'_int')],x[str(i+'_prod')]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
dev = (df.filter(like='measure').groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1)
         .diff(-1).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
         .rename(columns=lambda x: f"deviation_{x.split('_')[0]}"))

df = pd.concat([df, dev], axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
    id  measure1_int  measure2_int  measure1_prod  measure2_prod  deviation_measure1  deviation_measure2
0  123            45            23             16             45                  29                 -22
1  134             9            12             65              1                 -56                  11
```

However, maybe you can do better if you use your original dataframes:

```
# int -> df1
# prod -> df2
# deviation -> df3

df = pd.concat([df1.add_suffix('_int'),
                df2.add_suffix('_prod'),
                df3.add_prefix('deviation_')],
               axis=1).reset_index()
print(df)

# Output
    id  measure1_int  measure2_int  measure1_prod  measure2_prod  deviation_measure1  deviation_measure2
0  123            45            23             16             45                  29                 -22
1  134             9            12             65              1                 -56                  11
```

Comment: Hi @devarshi-goswami. Does it solved your problem?